# Eigen and std::vector

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a matrix, which is given as:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>> A;
```

And I want to map that to the Eigen linear algebra library like this:

```
Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXcd, Eigen::RowMajor> mat(A.data(),51,51);
```

But the code fails with

```
error: no matching function for call to        
‘Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, -1, -1>, 1>::
```

Is there anyway to convert a vector of a vector so that Eigen can use it?

Comment: Why would you have a vector of vectors in the first place?

Comment: I thought this was an easy way to store a matrix?  What is a better way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Eigen uses contiguous memory, as does `std::vector`. However, the outer `std::vector` contains a contiguous set of `std::vector<std::complex<double> >`, each pointing to a different set of complex numbers (and can be different lengths). Therefore, the std "matrix" is not contiguous. What you can do is copy the data to the Eigen matrix, there are multiple ways of doing that. The simplest would be to loop over `i` and `j`, with a better option being something like

```
Eigen::MatrixXcd mat(rows, cols);
for(int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
    mat.col(i) = Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXcd> (A[i].data(), rows);
```