# How to bridge a JavaScript (ragged) array and an std::vector<std::vector<T>> object?

Tags: javascript, c++, eigen, emscripten

In JavaScript I have a list of "lines", each of which consists of indefinite number of "points", each of which has a form of `[x, y]`. So it is a 3D ragged array. Now I need to pass it to my C++ code with the help from emscripten ([embind](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html)). Here's declaration of the C++ function:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd f(const std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>& lines);
```

And I would like to get a list of lists (`[[m11, m12],[m22, m22],...]`) in JavaScript after calling `f`. How to write the binding code in this case (the stuff inside `EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS`, for example)?

**UPDATE**: I can now pass the JavaScript array to C++. The binding part is something like

```
typedef std::vector<double> Point;
typedef std::vector<Point> Line;
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(module) {
  register_vector<Line>("LineArray");
  register_vector<Point>("Line");
  register_vector<double>("Point");
  emscripten::function("f_wrapper", &f_wrapper);
}
```

where `f_wrapper` calls `f` but returns `vector<vector<double>>` instead of `MatrixXd`. Now the problem is that I can only get an empty JavaScript object after calling `f_wrapper`. The JavaScript is

```
var Module = require('./bind.js'); // the output of em++
var cppAllLines = new Module.LineArray();
// some initialization
var result = Module.f_wrapper(cppAllLines); // an empty "Line" object
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668485/eigen-and-stdvector/33669013).

Comment: @AviGinsburg It's the other way around.

Comment: Can you clarify why you mean by "empty" Line object? Based on your code, I have just created a small test of passing a LineArray into a C++ function from Javascript, which returns a Line back, and the communication seems to work both ways. I'm using Emscripten 1.35.23-64bit. http://pastebin.com/9g8vJFc9 and http://pastebin.com/P0BmKY3K

Comment: @MichalCharemza Aha! I treated it as a JavaScript array and thus checked the values like `result.length` or `result[0]` but found nothing defined. I should have looked into `emscripten/bind.h` to see what `register_vector` really does. Now I can visit the content normally. If you can write the comment into an answer I would like to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing an embound vector from a C++ function, such as

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> f_wrapper(...);
```

to Javascript

```
var result = Module.f_wrapper(...);
```

The `result` object is not a Javascript array that implements `length` property or array-indexed access, so it can appear "empty" if using these to access its data.

But it does expose `get` and `size` functions to access the vector:

```
console.log('Back from C++', result.size(), result.get(0).get(1));
```

(The double `get` is because we're returning a vector of vectors)

For completeness, looking into the prototype of the object returned, it seems to expose the following functions.

- `get`
- `push_back`
- `resize`
- `set`
- `size`

Slightly inconsistently it exposes `get` and `set` functions rather than an equivalent of the C++ [`at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) function. I suspect that it's not possible for an exactly equivalent function since [`at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) returns a reference which allows it to be used as a setter, which isn't possible in Javascript.

Comment: Does it automatically manage the deallocation? Does it work without memory leaks?

Comment: @Sohail My suspicion is yes, but this might be worthy of a separate question.

Comment: Where is the documentation for .get,push_back  function,How did you find this get function for myVector? Please post a link thnx

Comment: @BuddhikaChaturanga I don't think I found it in any documentation, I examined the object returned in the console in the browser.

Comment: @MichalCharemza Thanx bro for the reply!! I tried to find any emscripten reference or doc on those method but nothing found.That's why I asked.

Comment: @MichalCharemza I'm not confident that deallocation happens automatically. It's possible that a resize(0,0) is needed.