# How to return an array of unknown size in Enscripten?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, emscripten

I have a C/C++ function that returns two arrays each the size that is unknown before the call. I need to call this function from JavaScript. (For simplicity, one array is returned in the example).

```
extern "C" {
  void produce_object_3d(float* verts, int *num_verts);
}
```

Note that JavaScript does not know `std::vector` and `boost:array` and other types. I currently pre-allocate some space, but it will not work. Here is the code on the JavaScript side:

```
var verts_address = Module._malloc(FLOAT_SIZE*3*max_verts);
var nv_address = Module._malloc(INT_SIZE*1);
//
produce_object_3d (verts_address, nv_address);
//
var nverts = Module.HEAPU32[nv_address/INT_SIZE];
var verts = Module.HEAPF32.subarray(verts_address/FLOAT_SIZE, verts_address/FLOAT_SIZE + 3*nverts);
```

This is not efficient. Also what if the size of the result is large and there is not enough memory pre-allocated?

Comment: There's no way that C interface works the way you describe, it should be `float **verts` so that the C code can allocate it at the size it needs. Otherwise you have to pre-allocate in C, too.

Comment: As I mentioned, std::vector will not be callable when it is compiled into JAvaScript using Emscripten. I tagged as C++ because I want to find a solution to these for my C++ code. I actually internally implemented it in C++ using `<vector>` and other classes,  but the difficulty is with the JS-interface.

Comment: <vector> may actually work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35494467/how-to-bridge-a-javascript-ragged-array-and-an-stdvectorstdvectort-obj?rq=1  But not suitable for getting the elements.

Comment: @SohailSi Why wouldn't vector work? The embind implementation for vector gives you a .get(position) function. Is performance the reason?

Comment: I didn't know about *embind*. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular case using embind is a better option.
As per the official documentation

> For convenience, embind provides factory functions to register
>   std::vector (register_vector()) and std::map (register_map())
>   types:
>
> ```
> EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(stl_wrappers) {
>     register_vector<int>("VectorInt");
>     register_map<int,int>("MapIntInt");
> }
> ```

The returned object has methods like .get() and .size()