# Is there a direct, fast way to "map" list<VectorXd> to MatrixXd?

Tags: c++, height, eigen

I am looking for a direct, fast method to convert a `list<VectorXd>` to `MatrixXd`. How can I do that?

```
Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> listV(list<VectorXd>)
```

Doesn't compile.

I am also thinking about iterating over the `list<VectorXd>` and fill in the `MatrixXd` necessarily, but that could be slow and unnecessary.

Although I agree that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33668485/3834) is helpful to me in resolving my question, but I don't agree that the parent question is a duplicate for this one. The way to access `list` and `vector` can be different, so the question should remain open because *the answer is different.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eigen and std::vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668485/eigen-and-stdvector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not possible because the elements of the std::list are not sequentially stored in memory. So you'll have to process it one column at once, using Map on the std::vector. So only one loop over the elements of the std::list.