# Convert from std::vector<cv::Mat> to Eigen::Tensor without reallocation

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, vector, eigen

I have a `std::vector<cv::Mat>` which represents voxels in x,y,z dimensions.  Each `cv::Mat` in the vector is a cross section or slice of the volume.

Unfortunately, OpenCV doesn't offer any wrapper for this data type, so I decided to use a non-supported module from the Eigen library called Tensor. I cannot see any constructor in the documentation that would allow me to efficiently convert from `vector<cv::Mat> to`Eigen::Tensor` without needing to reallocate data.

What is the most efficient way to convert from `std::vector<cv::Mat>` to `Eigen::Tensor`?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668485/eigen-and-stdvector/33669013) and explains why it won't work without reallocation.

Comment: @AviGinsburg the question you linked does have a working solution: given that the OP didn't specify what he means by "convert a vector of a vector so that Eigen can use it" a sparse matrix will do ( you can Map a sparse matrix to a vector of vectors without relocation ). That said, I don't think Eigen supports sparse tensors...

Comment: you could read about cv::MatAllocator and Eigen::TensorMap; never used them myself, but it looks like you can use the former to allocate each mat data contiguously and the latter to map resulting data to a tensor expression without reallocations...

Comment: cv::Mat::data is allocated in a contiguous way by default. The problem is that ::data in a vector of cv::Mats is not contiguous because it's spaced with cv::Mat class data.

Comment: @MaxWalczak no, this has nothing to do with the vector, but with having all Mat's memory stored contiguously in a *single* block in order to be passed to a tensor ... for this reason you need a special MatAllocator ( keep in mind cv::Mat is dynamically allocated, the vector turns out just an array of pointers pairs, or something equivalent)

Comment: If number of vector items are not variable it 's better for you to use Mat of n-channels. In that case all the elements of channels would be in sequential memory order and makes the life easier for you in converting

Comment: How do I construct n-channel mat? What's the maximum number of channels? I remember there was MatND in OpenCV but it's now obsolete...

Comment: You can use (e.g.) `cv::Mat3f` for a matrix of `Vec3f`. For arbitrary sizes: `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec<float, 32> >`. Also, OpenCVs `Mat` and `Mat_` do support arbitrary dimensional arrays: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a156df5a1326dd5c30b187b0e721a5f57 (a similar constructor for `Mat_<type>` is available)