# Vector of Vectors in Eigen C++

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a 3D C++ vector of vectors defined as follows.

```
vector<vector<vector<float>>> vec3DCpp;
```

`vec3DCpp` has a variable size in each of its dimension. I am trying to find a data type in Eigen similar to vectors of vectors in C++. Does Eigen have anything similar to this? If it does, how would mapping `vec3DCpp` to `vec3DEigen` look like?

If this is not possible, is there anyway to convert/map `vec3DCpp` to an Eigen variable?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Note that vector of vector of vector is not the same thing as a 3D array. For one thing, a vector of 1000 vectors of 1000 vectors of 1000 floats will perform 1001001 allocations (and spread the data in that much different memory chunks), while an actual 3D array would perform just one.

Comment: maybe even more allocations than that, if they are not pre-allocated.

Comment: What if we already have `vec3DCpp` and we want to map it to some types in Eigen? Is this possible?

Comment: @AFP You are looking for the `Map` type https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eigen and std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668485/eigen-and-stdvector)

Comment: Are you sure you need such a type? Maybe a std::vector<Eigen::Matrix> would be sufficient?

Comment: Have you considered using [the Tensor module](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/unsupported/group__CXX11__Tensor__Module.html)?